# How to fix IMG align="left" to be W3C valid?

Tags: image, w3c, w3c-validation, alignment

How to *fix* `<img align="left"` problem to be **W3C** valid?

Comment: Depends... By default, lines are left-aligned. Is your image in an inline context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `float` to position the element to the right/left. It also pays to learn the other css positioning methods (eg, absolute, relative, and float).

Example:

```
<img style="float: left">
```

Docs: http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_float.asp

**CSS Positioning Tutorial:** 
http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/

Answer (score 1):

use css style="float: left or right;"

Answer (score 0):

try to use a css file (example: style.css) and use (ALT=" ") tag. Missing " ALT " tag form   also a cause of W3C VALIDATION ERROR.